# var reference in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I have appComponent, and `this.loggedIn = this.authenticationService.isLogged;` in it.

So appComponent uses authenticationService and takes isLogged data from it. I suppose `this.loggedIn` has reference to service data?

Now when I run method from appComponent:

```
logout() {
    this.authenticationService.isLogged = false;
}
```

`this.loggedIn` should change to false. But it doesn't.

Here part of appComponent.ts:

```
import {AuthenticationService} from './auth_service/auth_service';
@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
styleUrls: ['app/app_component.css'],
templateUrl: './app/main_app_template.html',
directives: [ ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
providers: [ SendLoginService, AuthenticationService, ConfigurationService, SetupIntervalService]
})

export class AppComponent  {
loggedIn ;
constructor (private authenticationService: AuthenticationService
}
ngOnInit () {
    this.loggedIn = this.authenticationService.isLogged;
}
 logout() {
    this.authenticationService.isLogged = false;
    console.log(this.loggedIn);   //returns:  true . but should return 'false'
}
```

authenticationService.ts :

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
@Injectable ()
 export class AuthenticationService extends HttpBaseClass {
isLogged = true;
  }
```

Comment: I have updated my answer, will you check it ?

Answer (score 0):

It is because the reference to a basic type like boolean, string or number won't work (thats how JavaScript works). You will be good if you will wrap `isLogged` in an object, like that:

```
userAuth ={
    isLogged:true
}
```

Comment: I've tried with Object referance: 
this.authenticationService.userAuth.isLogged = false;     
        console.log(this.authenticationService.userAuth.isLogged);     (FALSE)
        console.log(this.loggedIn); (TRUE)

Answer (score 0):

primitive types including boolean is pased by value. So the `this.loggedIn` won't change if you update the value in service instance

```
 logout() {
    this.authenticationService.isLogged = false;
this.loggedIn = false,
}
```

JS [types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures) and [primitive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please update your service with this code, and let me know if your problem is still there ?

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
@Injectable ()
 export class AuthenticationService extends HttpBaseClass {
     isLogged:boolean = true;

      logout(){
          isLogged = false;  
     }

     isLoggedIn(){
          return isLogged;
     }

  }
```

And update your AppComponent like this -

```
export class AppComponent  {
loggedIn ;
constructor (private authenticationService: AuthenticationService
}
ngOnInit () {

}
 logout() {
    this.authenticationService.logout();
    this.loggedIn = this.authenticationService.isLoggedIn();
    console.log(this.loggedIn);  
}
```

Comment: still returns 'true'

Answer (score 0):

It occurs **because** the value was passes a **copy** (value) and not by **reference**, you **need** to use **authenticationService** and access **directly** the **authenticationService.isLogged** passing the new value;

**As request, an example**:

```
import {AuthenticationService} from './auth_service/auth_service';
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    styleUrls: ['app/app_component.css'],
    templateUrl: './app/main_app_template.html',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: [SendLoginService, AuthenticationService, ConfigurationService, SetupIntervalService]
})
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) { }

    logout() {
        this.authenticationService.isLogged = false;
        console.log(this.authenticationService.isLogged);   //now should returns false
    }
}
```

Comment: can you write a small example?